# OpenRouteServices to replace Google Maps API in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have the following VBA Code that is working as intended but the cost of Google Services is to high for what I need this for. I want to move to OpenRouteServices API and can not seem to find the right way to make that code work.

```vb
' Returns the number of seconds it would take to get from one place to another
Function TRAVELDISTANCE(origin, destination, apikey)
 
    Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & origin & "&destination=" & destination & "&key=" & apikey
     
    Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With httpReq
         .Open "GET", strUrl, False
         .send
    End With
     
    Dim response As String
    response = httpReq.responseText
     
    Dim parsed As Dictionary
    Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
     
    Dim leg As Dictionary
     
     
    For Each leg In parsed("routes")(1)("legs")
        meters = meters + leg("distance")("value")
    Next leg
     
     
     
    TRAVELDISTANCE = meters
 
End Function
```

I need to insert the following to use ORS.

https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car?api_key=5b3ce3597851110001cf6248abe2e5a2809b4987b0b2bd083a5e0ba5&start=8.681495,49.41461&end=8.687872,49.420318

I have tried to insert the code with a few edits with no luck.

Comment: The json response from ORS is not the same as from google maps, so you need to look at the new format and change the way you treat the response JSON object.  eg - it looks like `parsed("features")(1)("properties")("summary")("distance")` has the total distance.

Answer (score 0):

The json response from ORS is not the same as from google maps, so you need to look at the new format and change the way you treat the response JSON object.

It looks like
`parsed("features")(1)("properties")("summary")("distance")`
has the total distance.

For example:

```vb
Sub tester22()
    Debug.Print TRAVELDISTANCE("8.681495,49.41461", "8.687872,49.420318", _
                                "5b3ce3597851110001cf6248abe2e5a2809b4987b0b2bd083a5e0ba5")
End Sub

Function TRAVELDISTANCE(origin, destination, apikey)
 
    Dim strUrl As String, response As String, parsed As Dictionary
    Dim httpReq As Object
    
    strUrl = "https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car?" & _
             "api_key=" & apikey & _
             "&start=" & origin & _
             "&end=" & destination
     
    Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With httpReq
         .Open "GET", strUrl, False
         .send
    End With
     
    response = httpReq.responseText
    Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
     
    TRAVELDISTANCE = parsed("features")(1)("properties")("summary")("distance")
 
End Function
```

Sample response JSON:

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "metadata": {
    "attribution": "openrouteservice.org | OpenStreetMap contributors",
    "service": "routing",
    "timestamp": 1692651863666,
    "query": {
      "coordinates": [
        [
          8.681495,
          49.41461
        ],
        [
          8.687872,
          49.420318
        ]
      ],
      "profile": "driving-car",
      "format": "json"
    },
    "engine": {
      "version": "7.1.0",
      "build_date": "2023-07-09T01:31:50Z",
      "graph_date": "2023-08-20T10:24:28Z"
    }
  },
  "bbox": [
    8.681423,
    49.414599,
    8.690123,
    49.420514
  ],
  "features": [
    {
      "bbox": [
        8.681423,
        49.414599,
        8.690123,
        49.420514
      ],
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "transfers": 0,
        "fare": 0,
        "segments": [
          {
            "distance": 1408.8,
            "duration": 281.9,
            "steps": [
              {
                "distance": 1.8,
                "duration": 0.4,
                "type": 11,
                "instruction": "Head west on Gerhart-Hauptmann-Straße",
                "name": "Gerhart-Hauptmann-Straße",
                "way_points": [
                  0,
                  1
                ]
              },
              {
                "distance": 313.8,
                "duration": 75.3,
                "type": 1,
                "instruction": "Turn right onto Wielandtstraße",
                "name": "Wielandtstraße",
                "way_points": [
                  1,
                  6
                ]
              },
              {
                "distance": 500.8,
                "duration": 76.4,
                "type": 1,
                "instruction": "Turn right onto Mönchhofstraße",
                "name": "Mönchhofstraße",
                "way_points": [
                  6,
                  15
                ]
              },
              {
                "distance": 251.9,
                "duration": 60.5,
                "type": 0,
                "instruction": "Turn left onto Erwin-Rohde-Straße",
                "name": "Erwin-Rohde-Straße",
                "way_points": [
                  15,
                  19
                ]
              },
              {
                "distance": 126.8,
                "duration": 30.4,
                "type": 1,
                "instruction": "Turn right onto Moltkestraße",
                "name": "Moltkestraße",
                "way_points": [
                  19,
                  20
                ]
              },
              {
                "distance": 83,
                "duration": 7.5,
                "type": 2,
                "instruction": "Turn sharp left onto Handschuhsheimer Landstraße, B 3",
                "name": "Handschuhsheimer Landstraße, B 3",
                "way_points": [
                  20,
                  22
                ]
              },
              {
                "distance": 130.6,
                "duration": 31.4,
                "type": 0,
                "instruction": "Turn left onto Roonstraße",
                "name": "Roonstraße",
                "way_points": [
                  22,
                  23
                ]
              },
              {
                "distance": 0,
                "duration": 0,
                "type": 10,
                "instruction": "Arrive at Roonstraße, straight ahead",
                "name": "-",
                "way_points": [
                  23,
                  23
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "summary": {
          "distance": 1408.8,
          "duration": 281.9
        },
        "way_points": [
          0,
          23
        ]
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            8.681495,
            49.414599
          ],
          [
            8.68147,
            49.414599
          ],
          [
            8.681488,
            49.41465
          ],
          [
            8.681423,
            49.415746
          ],
          [
            8.681656,
            49.41659
          ],
          [
            8.681826,
            49.417081
          ],
          [
            8.681881,
            49.417392
          ],
          [
            8.682461,
            49.417389
          ],
          [
            8.682676,
            49.417387
          ],
          [
            8.683595,
            49.417372
          ],
          [
            8.68536,
            49.417365
          ],
          [
            8.686407,
            49.417365
          ],
          [
            8.68703,
            49.41736
          ],
          [
            8.687467,
            49.417351
          ],
          [
            8.688212,
            49.417358
          ],
          [
            8.688802,
            49.417381
          ],
          [
            8.68871,
            49.418194
          ],
          [
            8.688647,
            49.418465
          ],
          [
            8.688539,
            49.418964
          ],
          [
            8.688398,
            49.41963
          ],
          [
            8.690123,
            49.419833
          ],
          [
            8.689854,
            49.420217
          ],
          [
            8.689653,
            49.420514
          ],
          [
            8.687871,
            49.420322
          ]
        ],
        "type": "LineString"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I will let you know the results.

Comment: (UPDATE: I put the code in and I am getting hits but errors showing ORS. I will work on it when some more, but thank you for the great start and help.)